# Moisture Absorbancy & Odor Elimination

Tags: everyday-chemistry, home-experiment

What would be the typical DRY ingredients in moisture absorbing and odor eliminating materials that work especially well on perspiration/organic odors?

Comment: Why type of clothing/application do you have in mind? You can't really absorb much moisture, the body makes a lot. It is more of a matter of wicking it away to increase  surface area and speed evaporation.

Comment: Thanks for question --  Application will be for removing moisture and odor from athletic shoes, gloves, gear.  I appreciate your thoughts!

Answer (score 1):

Silica gel is often used to absorb moisture; activated carbon is effective at odor removal; and zeolites (also called molecular sieves) come in different varieties and can be effective for both purposes.